# Recode bgen files against reference genome

Tags: software-recommendation, human-genome

I have a set of .bgen files split by chromosomes, including both SNPs and INDELS (named with both rsids and chr_pos_a1_a2). I know a large portion of them are encoded on the wrong strand, and I want to recode them against a reference genome (in my case, 1KGP).

How can I recode the variants in my starting files against the reference genome?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.